# Setting up React-project: What does Babelify do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, browserify, babeljs

I'm currently learning how to set up React-projects with npm, Babel and Browserify.

The usage of Babel seems sufficient clear to me: It translates JSX- and ES6-code to ES5-code, which can be run in all browsers.

The same with Browserify: It bundles the npm-packages which I use (React-DOM, React etc.) together with my own code into one large file. These file can then be used for to be deployed to production.

But I struggle to understand what **Babelify** is for. 
I have read that it "allows to use Babel with Browserify". A sitepoint-article says that it is "Babel transformer for Browserify".

All these explanations are a bit weird to me because if:

Babel is a transpiler which transpiles JSX, ES6, TypeScript, ... -code to browser-compatible code. 
**Why do I need an additional "transformer" for the output of Babel?**

Comment: Basically, Babelify plugs both Browserify and Babel together, so both run as a single integrated pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`babelify` it's browserify transform package.

You can not use plain `babel` package with browserify. Therefore you should use `babelify` package, which contains `babel` inside to be able transform es6 code to es5 using browserify.

Comment: Babelify transforms the code WITHIN the npm-packages. The npm-packages which I've included by using Babel. Have I get that right?

Comment: I don't properly understand you, `babelify` includes `babel` package. Yes it transforms es6 code.

Comment: I mean: It looks at the code IN the npm-modules and translates that into ES5? When there is ES6-code used in the npm-modules (React, React-DOM and so on).

Comment: @mizech, yes, all code you require in your application will be transformed from es6 to es5